# Android Camera Capture - switch Font/Rear Camera Image Doesn't Upload

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera

I am having an issue with taking a picture within the app and uploading it to the backend. When a user takes a picture with the front camera everything works well. However, if the user switches to the rear camera and takes a picture, then the image is not being uploaded. I have no idea why it is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have this code:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <provider
        android:authorities="com.packagename.fileprovider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileprovider"/>
    </provider>
```

XML File Provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="images"
        path="Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

then in Activity:

```
companion object {
        private val MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = "image/jpg".toMediaType()
        private const val REQUEST_CODE = 42
        private lateinit var photoFile: File
        private const val FILE_NAME = "photo.jpg"
        private var imageFromCameraGlobal: Bitmap? = null
        private var imageFromCameraGlobalPath: String? = null
    }


imageUploadButton.setOnClickListener {

        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        photoFile = getPhotoFile(FILE_NAME)
        val fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.packagename.fileprovider", photoFile)
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider)
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null){
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

private fun getPhotoFile(fileName: String): File {

        val storageDirectory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(fileName,".jpg",storageDirectory)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        val takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.absolutePath)
        val imgString = takenImage.toString()
        Picasso.get().load(photoFile).fit().centerCrop().into(imageProfileUpload)
        imageFromCameraGlobalPath = photoFile.absolutePath
        uploadImage()

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}

fun uploadImage(){

        val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()

                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("AuthenticationToken",GlobalActivity.authenticationToken)
                .addFormDataPart("ProfileImage","profile-image.jpg", File("${imageFromCameraGlobalPath}").asRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG))
                .build()
        val urlDirectory = "upload-image.php"
        val url = GlobalActivity.globalUrl+urlDirectory
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Error"+e)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val myPassResponse = gson.fromJson(body, MyPassResponse::class.java)
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: You could replace `File("${imageFromCameraGlobalPath}")` with `photoFile`. Beyond that, note that you need to retain the path for `photoFile` across process termination, as your app's process might be terminated when the camera app is in the foreground. You can use the saved instance state `Bundle` for this.

Comment: I just changed it to this: `.addFormDataPart("ProfileImage","profile-image.jpg",photoFile.asRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG))` but it still doesn't work. Do I need do anything else?

Comment: "Do I need do anything else?" -- most of my comment is for a separate step: saving the value of `photoFile` across process termination. Beyond that, you could examine Logcat to see if your `onError()` is reporting anything, and you could add other `Log` statements to see if there is anything unusual going on in `uploadImage()` (such as `photoFile` being `null`).